# Not able to send email in java using SMTP,its blocked by firewall in my office.Is there any other method by which we can send mail?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, email

There are 2 java files and a xml file. Not able to send email using smtp. Please help:

Springmail.xml

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.office365.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />

        <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />

        <property name="username" value="xxxxx@xyz.com" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxxx" />

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>

                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtps</prop> 

<!--                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol.rfc822">smtps</prop> -->

                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>

                <prop key="mail.smtps.quitwait">false</prop>

                <prop key="mail.smtps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>

                <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">30000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="mailMail" class="com.mkyong.common.MailMail">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="simpleMailMessage" ref="customeMailMessage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customeMailMessage"
        class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

        <property name="from" value="xxxxx@xyz.com" />
        <property name="to" value="xxxxx@xyz.com" />
        <property name="subject" value="Testing Subject" />
        <property name="text">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[
                Dear %s,
                Mail Content : %s
            ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

mailMail.java
There are 2 java files and a xml file. Not able to send email using smtp. Please help

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.mail.MailParseException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

public class MailMail
{
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;

    public void setSimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {
        this.simpleMailMessage = simpleMailMessage;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String dear, String content) {

        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        try{
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

            helper.setFrom(simpleMailMessage.getFrom());
            helper.setTo(simpleMailMessage.getTo());
            helper.setSubject(simpleMailMessage.getSubject());
            helper.setText(String.format(
                    simpleMailMessage.getText(), dear, content));

            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(
                    "C:\\vivek\\BDD_13thMay\\cucumber.json");

            helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);


        }catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new MailParseException(e);
        }
        mailSender.send(message);


    }


}
```

App.java

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Mail.xml");

        MailMail mm = (MailMail) context.getBean("mailMail");
        mm.sendMail("Yong Mook Kim", "This is text content");
    }
}
```

The Console shows following details:
There are 2 java files and a xml file. Not able to send email using smtp. Please help

```
Jun 09, 2015 12:59:19 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6041f871: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6041f871]; startup date [Tue Jun 09 12:59:19 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 09, 2015 12:59:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml]
Jun 09, 2015 12:59:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6041f871]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ce1bafc
Jun 09, 2015 12:59:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ce1bafc: defining beans [mailSender,mailMail,customeMailMessage]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL true
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:342)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:338)
    at com.mkyong.common.MailMail.sendMail(MailMail.java:47)
    at com.mkyong.common.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:205)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Check your firewall. It could be blocking your access to that port. Try connecting directly using telnet to that host and port to see if you get a connection.

Answer (score 0):

I can connect to office365.com on port 587 using telnet, and there is a mail server on the other end.

(On linux, I ran "telnet office365.com 587" ...)

Apparently you can't connect.  Or at least, the Java app you are running can't connect.

The most likely explanation that there is a firewall that is blocking the out-going connection:

- Check your computer's firewall rules.
- If you are doing this from home, check your router / modem's firewall rules.  If that fails, talk to your ISP.
- If you are doing this from work (or school) talk to your network administrator(s).

Comment: Yes I am working in office so there must be some firewall.So can you explain in simple words,how to use telnet to get past this.
Thanks

Comment: Talk to your company / office network administrator.

Comment: In simple words, you **cannot** use telnet to get past a firewall ... or this problem in a broader sense.  I was just using telnet as a diagnostic tool to see if I could open a TCP/IP connection to the server.